# UITextView Change URL

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView that has a text of say www.foo.com

when the user clicks on it I want to visit www.foo.com/bar/cow/index.html instead of what appears in the text property of the UITextView

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have your class conform to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol. Then implement `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` in a similar way:

```
 - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<additionalTextHere>", textView.text]; 
    //do whetever with url


}
```

Comment: I think you mean `UITextViewDelegate`, and all the other relevant changes.

Comment: I made the class conform to the UITextViewDelegate.  Set the delegate of the UITextView object to self - still I do not get a breakpoint in the

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{ }

Comment: @drewmm thanks, edited the answer. OneGyuInDc: that should get fired. Check your view/properties/outlets, setting of delegates, etc.